# process.env.URL null in nuxt project onvercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, vercel

I am deploying nuxt app on vercel. I added a secret to vercel environment following this guide - https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables#secret-environment-variables

Locally I am using dotenv and it is working well, loading the variable from .env file into `process.env.Token` but `process.env.Token` is null when deployed on vercel.

How to solve this?

Comment: Where are you trying to access those variables from ? From Vue code ? Because then the variables maybe have to look a bit differently : https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables -> `VUE_APP_Token`

Comment: on local machine I am using .env and it just works fine. The question is about deploying on vercel

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me in Nuxtjs, just set your name of environment variable starting with **NUXT_ENV_**

For example

```
process.env.NUXT_ENV_Token
```

Vercel will be automatically injected into the process environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just like React, Next or Vue, Nux builds your pages. You should try to provide the environment during the build phase, in the `nuxt.config.js`.

You can find a nice example just here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env/